# How to resolve 'System.InvalidCastException' when calculating in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am trying to add horizontally across rows and vertically down a column in my DataGridView in C#, but I get this error message each time I try to enter data:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>   occured in mscorlib.dll.    Additional information: object cannot be
>   cast from DBNull to other types".

These are my codes:

```
 private void tbl_valuesDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //totalling horizontally across rows
        int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
        int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);

        tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = val1 + val2;

         //adding vertically down the total column to get Grand Total 
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value); 
        }
        textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

POINTS TO NOTE:

1. The DataGridView has the following columns; id which auto
   increments, value1, value2 and total. In addition, there is a
   textbox in my form that shows the Grand Total (i.e. totalling all
   the values in the total column).
2. In the sql server database table, id is the primary key column with type int, values 1,2 & total  are of type 'money' and allow null.
3. If I change the row indexes in my code to 0,1 & 2, I don't get any error but the system adds the ID (index 0) to Value1(index 1). However, when I change it to 1,2 & 3, that is when I get the error.

I am new to programming, so I don't know whether the error is as a result of the way I setup the database table, or whether it is with my C# code.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Anik's help and some debugging, I was able to get the answer to my question. For those of us who are new to programming, you will find this code very helpful if you intend working with DataGridView. Always ensure you use the CellEndEdit event handler for this code.

```
 private void tbl_valuesDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //totalling horizontally across rows
        int val1 = 0, val2 = 0, demo1;

        if (int.TryParse(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim(), out demo1))
            val1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);

        if (int.TryParse(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim(), out demo1))
            val2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);

        tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = val1 + val2;


        //Adding vertically down the total column
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(tbl_valuesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value); //where 1 represents the index of the column you are adding
        }
        textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your horizontal addition code, you set Cells[3].Value equal to Cells[1].Value + Cells[2].Value. 
This is fine, but you appear to be doing it for one row only.

Then in your vertical addition you're totalling Cells[2].Value from all rows.

If I understand the code correctly, you should be totalling Cells[3].Value here (as this is where the total for each row is stored).

In any case, you need to go to the line where the exception is thrown, and examine each variable in the debugger Watch window. This should tell you which object is in an incorrect state.